# TikZ multi-part rectangle with dashed line separating parts?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, tikz-node

How does one put a dashed line between the parts, say like this?

[image: multipart rectangle with dashed line separating parts]

Comment: easy with tcolorbox --see the documentation at page 12 -- https://ctan.um.ac.ir/macros/latex/contrib/tcolorbox/tcolorbox.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm afraid you have to dig into how the split parts are done. Don't know if it's possible to automatize this, maybe with a postaction.

[image: rectangle split with dashed line]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=2,draw,rectangle split draw splits=false] (A) {TEXT \nodepart{two}TWO};
        \draw[densely dashed] (A.text split west) -- (A.text split east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And an exemple with three parts, just to show that you can customize each splitting line differently:

[image: rectagle split with two different split lines]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node[rectangle split,rectangle split parts=3,draw,rectangle split draw splits=false] (A) {TEXT \nodepart{two}TWO \nodepart{three}THREE};
        \draw[densely dashed] (A.text split west) -- (A.text split east);
        \draw[orange,densely dotted, thick] (A.two split west) -- (A.two split east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```